# How to sort a multimap of strings as the value

Tags: c++, sorting

Right now I have a `

```
 multimap<size_t, <string>> mymap`;
```

It stores words keyed by the word size.

I want to be able to grab all the words with key = 5. Then I want to sort the strings with that key value from lowest to highest.

How would I do this and is a multimap the most efficient way? 
I mean is it possible to use a different container where I could sort them by string values as well as categorize them by key values?

Basically I have a vector where the first element must not be moved. But the rest of the vector should be organized alphabetically. How would I do this? I would then want to organize the vectors once sorted again, alphabeticallly using the first word only to organize them inside the multimap. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you mean that the data of the map is a *vector* of strings?

Comment: Have you thought about having a `std::unordered_map<std::size_t, std::set<std::string>>`?  This was you can have the string organized by there size and stored lexicographical.

Answer (score 1):

The most efficient way depends on how you will use this container.
If you want keep strings sorted while you inserting/deleting them, then most efficient way is `std::unordered_map<std::size_t, set<string> >`.

However, if it is possible to collect all the data and then sort all strings, then the most efficient way is to use `std::unordered_map<std::size_t, vector<string> >`.

Comment: I have a vector where the first element must not be moved. But the rest of the vector should be organized alphabetically. How would I do this? 
I would then want to organize the vectors alphabeticallly using the first word only to organize them inside the multimap.  Any ideas?

Comment: Regarding first point. You can sort only the part of the vector (starting from the vec.begin() + 1), however, don't forget about checking size.
Regarding second point, I am not sure that I understood what do you mean correctly.

Comment: That was actually a perfect answer and helped me figure it out. I'll post my solution soon :)

Comment: I'm happy to hear that :)